# node internal process promises 288

Tags: node.js, node-modules

How can fix this thank you. node:internal/process/promises:288 where is the this file

```
     triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
            ^

[Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\whatsapp-chatgpt-master\whatsapp-chatgpt-master\db.tmp.json' -> 'C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\whatsapp-chatgpt-master\whatsapp-chatgpt-master\db.json'] {
  errno: -4058,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'rename',
  path: 'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\whatsapp-chatgpt-master\\whatsapp-chatgpt-master\\db.tmp.json',
  dest: 'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\whatsapp-chatgpt-master\\whatsapp-chatgpt-master\\db.json'
}

Node.js v18.17.0
```